How to show this bounded sequence must be constant
I'm given the following:
$$(n+1)^2(a_{n+1}-a_n^2)=a_{n+1}-1$$
With:
$a_n \in [\frac{1}{n+1},2]$.
We can show that:
$ -\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq a_{n+1} - a_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$
My goal is to show the sequence must be constant at $1$ by considering $a_n>1$ and $a_n<1$ and finding that each case contradicts the range of the sequence.
First I want to show that we cannot have $a_n>1$ for $n$ large enough:
Intuitively, the inequality tells us that $a_{n+1} \approx a_n^2$, and thus the sequence would grow without bound, contradicting the first condition. Is this valid reasoning? If yes, how can I make it more rigorous?

Firstly we rewrite the recurrence as
\begin{equation}
(n^2 + 2n)a_{n+1} = (n+1)^2a_n^2 - 1
\end{equation}
which gives us
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + \frac{a_n^2 - 1}{(n^2 + 2n)}
\end{equation}
Importantly, if $a_n > 1$, then $a_{n + 1} > a_n^2$.
Now let $a_1 = 1 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$, this gives us $a_2 = (1 + \epsilon)^2 + \frac{\epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon}{3} = 1+\frac{8}{3}\epsilon + \frac{4}{3}\epsilon^2$ or more easily we just note $a_2 > a_1^2 > 1 + 2\epsilon$, similarly $a_3 > a_2^2 > 1 + 4\epsilon$, that is $a_n > 1 + 2^n\epsilon$. This tells us that $a_n$ will grow exponentially and will certainly get bigger than $2$.
I leave the other case to you.
